# how to change soap 1.2 response from wso2 authorization of token

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I am getting the following response if I pass the wrong token to API in SOAP 1.2 format

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
    <soapenv:Body>
        <soapenv:Fault>
            <soapenv:Code>
                <soapenv:Value>**soapenv:Client**</soapenv:Value>
            </soapenv:Code>
            <soapenv:Reason>
                <soapenv:Text xml:lang="en">Authentication Failure</soapenv:Text>
            </soapenv:Reason>
            <soapenv:Detail>Access failure for API: ***/1.0, version: 1.0 status: (900901) - Invalid Credentials</soapenv:Detail>
        </soapenv:Fault>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

instead of **soapenv:Client** we need **soapenv:Sender** how it is possible?

Answer (score 0):

**soapenv:Client** is the default value that is sent from the code itself. See [1]. This can be changed by writing a custom APIAuthenticationHandler. Please refer [2] for information.

[1] [https://github.com/wso2/carbon-apimgt/blob/master/components/apimgt/org.wso2.carbo[…]/apimgt/gateway/handlers/security/APIAuthenticationHandler.java](https://github.com/wso2/carbon-apimgt/blob/master/components/apimgt/org.wso2.carbo%5B%E2%80%A6%5D/apimgt/gateway/handlers/security/APIAuthenticationHandler.java)

[2] https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/develop/extending-api-manager/extending-gateway/writing-custom-handlers/#writing-a-custom-handler

Comment: can you consider this as Bug in wso2 3.0.0